# Careers public URL

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

I was wondering if just simply typing in a name in the edit box in the [page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish) to publish my CV is enough to reserve the public URL. I noticed the UI seemed to think this step was done as it updated the item with the green check mark, but I was wondering if I have to publish the CV in order to reserve the URL?

I think the URL is automatically reserved as soon as I typed it in, but I kept looking for a "Save" button or something, probably after being trained to do so by years of using crappy websites with low-usability. Am I correct in my assumption of your awesomeness?

Comment: +1 for "Am I correct in my assumption of your awesomeness?"  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL is reserved as soon as you get the green check mark. If you typed in a URL that someone else was using, you'd get a red X and a "name already exists" message:

[image]